# Ada Strings Fixed

Tags: types, ada, gnat

Hi everyone ,

```
type String is array (Positive range <>) of Character;
```

Ok but , where is the limit when we declare a variable ?

When we do this :

```
max_String : String( 1 .. integer'last ) ;
```

It failed .

---

For instance :

```
With Ada.Text_IO ;          Use Ada.Text_IO ;

Procedure fixed is

  max_String : String( 1 .. integer'last ) ;

begin
    get ( max_String ) ;
    put ( max_String ) ;

End fixed ;
```

Compilator : " fixed.adb:3:1: error: total size of local objects too large "

Thanks.

Comment: System dependent. A local variable will be allocated on the stack, so if you *need* a 2GB string, you either need to set a higher stack size, or something like `max_String : access String := new String(1 .. integer'last);` to allocate your string on the heap.

Comment: I prefer to not dealling with pointers at the moment . i have no idea of how to set a higher stack size, but could be the best solution .

Comment: "System dependent" . So , Is there any way to know what the limit for my system is , when i use a String ?

Comment: You almost certainly don't *need* to allocate 2 gigabytes to hold a string. Tweaking your OS configuration to let you do that (a) is not helpful, and (b) may not even be possible.

Comment: I just want to know the limit  .  :-(

Comment: The message is from the bowels of gcc, so not Ada specific (although it was contributed by GNAT, I think). A function that checks stack frame size is found in file *gcc/function.c*. The question should perhaps first be asked on the GCC help list. If there is no user documentation that addresses this system dependency of the respective installation of GCC, then I'd say this is a bug, as it affects portability of perfectly normal array declarations.

Comment: In ancient times the default was 2MB in windows, if memory serves me correctly. The user's guide should give you the way to modify this. Or you could roughly find it by trial-and-error ;-)

Answer (score 3):

When you create a string, it has the length you specify. So

```
S : String (1 .. 5);
```

reserves space for 5 characters.

```
L : String := “foo”;
```

reserves space for 3 characters and fills it with ‘f’, ‘o’, ‘o’.

`Integer’Last` is about 2 billion; I don’t think you have that much RAM!

You probably want to use the function version of `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Fixed is
   S : constant String := Get_Line;
begin
   Put_Line (S);
end Fixed;
```

This initializes `S` with whatever the first input line happens to be.

Most people who have to deal with strings use `Unbounded_Strings` (needs a link - the ARM website is down at the moment)

Comment: Yes , Unbounded_Strings are more appropriate in the exemple . Also , i don't want to use get_line .  I really want to answer my first question .

Answer (score 1):

Objects declared in a declarative block are allocated on the stack of the task they are running in.

This means that the limit is derived from how much stack space your operating system gives the program, when you run it.

I use Zsh on Linux, where I can check/adjust the assigned stack size with the command `limit stacksize`:

`% limit stacksize
stacksize       8MB
%`

I can also change it:

`% limit stacksize 2100m
% limit stacksize
stacksize       2100MB
%`

If I started your program at this point (from the same shell), it might work fine.

Comment: Check `ulimit`, but be warned that it only applies to descendants of the current session and it might serve only to restrict (not enlarge) if you're not root.

Comment: IIRC, you can also adjust the stack size requested by the application at compile-time.  I just can't remember how.